# heap corruption detected after delete call in visual c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I'm trying to run my c++ code of which introduction of this new code has brought this memory corruption, can any one help me out what would be causing this. After the delete call I'm facing this issue. I also tried placing the `newArgs[SZ] = '\0';` after each `strncpy` call.

The error says:

> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED after Normal Block(#274) at 0X00C09600 etc

```
int main(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, char* argc, int nShowCmd){

    MyClass *obj;
    char args[] = " hello world";
    int SZ = strlen(args);
    int argsLength = 0;

    if(argc != NULL)
        argsLength=strlen(argc);
    SZ+=argsLength;
    char *newArgs = new char[SZ];
    strncpy(newArgs, "",SZ);

    if(argc != NULL)
        strncpy(newArgs, argc,argsLength);

    StrCat(newArgs,args);

    obj = new MyClass(newArgs);
    delete[] newArgs;

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What's `SIZE`? It's used, but never declared.

Comment: You are adding `argsLength` to `SIZE` not `SZ`, so `newArgs` won't be big enough.

Comment: `int main(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, char* argc, int nShowCmd)` What is that?

Comment: `{std::string newArgs = args; newArgs += argc; }`  That is probably what all of that code boils down to.

Comment: He probably meant to write SZ instead of SIZE, but the issue there is that SZ should be one more for the terminating null character.

Comment: @drescherjm Most likely, `WinMain` renamed to `main` via `/ENTRY` switch, for reasons unclear.

Answer (score 3):

You are retrieving the string length of argc. This is without the trailing null byte:

```
argsLength=strlen(argc);
```

Later you are copying argc to your buffer. But you are only copying argsLength characters, which is the string without the trailing null byte. strncpy will then only copy the string content and not add the trailing null byte itself (see man strncpy).

```
strncpy(newArgs, argc,argsLength);
```

Immediately after strncpy you are appending another string to your newArgs.

```
StrCat(newArgs,args);
```

Depending on the content of newArgs after allocation (which might be random, in debug it probably will be filled with a special pattern) strcat fill not find a trailing null byte in newArgs and will thus read beyond the end of the allocated buffer (until it finds a null byte) and will append your string args there - somewhere in the heap and outside your allocated memory. This is a heap corruption.

Besides:

1. When allocating the memory you need one byte more for the trailing null byte.
2. What's the use of strncpy(..., "", SZ)?
3. Use std::string, not error prone C strings.
4. You are leaking the allocated MyClass object.
5. In C++ string literals are const.

I would rewrite your program this way (did not compile and test it):

```
int main(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, char* argc, int nShowCmd)
{
    const char args[] = " hello world";
    std::string newArgs;
    if(argc != NULL)
        newArgs = argc;
    newArgs += args;

    // Use the line that you prefer
    MyClass obj1(newArgs.c_str());
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> obj2(new MyClass(newArgs.c_str()));

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: how do i get the length of argc and the use of this is strncpy(..., "", SZ) is to initialize the array with empty characters initially as it fills up garbage by default.

Comment: length of argc is: strlen(argc) characters plus one trailing null byte. So when concatenating str1 and str2 your destination buffer must be strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1 byte long. strncpy(..., "", SZ) will copy no byte (if SZ==0) or only the terminating null byte of "" (if SZ>0). If you want to fill the array with null bytes (which is not necessary because you overwrite them later) you need to memset or std::fill.

Comment: but you've said that argc doesn't have a null terminating character, so does strlen determine its length?

Comment: @suj: No, I did not say that. If argc is "me", then you have three bytes: 'm', 'e' and the terminating null byte '\0', so the memory that argc points to is 3 bytes long. strlen(argc) returns 2 because there are two characters in the string. You really should Google/learn about how strings are represented in C :-).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your `MyClass` implementation but I would be willing to bet that It keeps a copy of the pointer passed into it's constructor and that it is also trying to work with that after your `delete` call.

I'd strongly recommend that you stop `new`ing `char*`s in C++ and use `strings`.